# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs after login at splash screen. Grub recovery mode boots

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

I am having an issue where Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is not booting for me after what seemed to be a routine update. The machine boots up apparently normally and even shows the login screen.  After I enter my password, the screen reverts to the splash screen and while the hard drive appears to be working, the machine is unresponsive.

If I boot into grub, and use the recovery mode (Linux 5.0.0.31-generic) instead of the normal boot, I can boot successfully.  Apparently, even my NVIDIA drivers (435.21) and CUDA work after booting through recovery mode.

One thing that was suggested is that I flash the firmware on my motherboard, an ASUS Z170-A, to the latest version as this might resolve some incompatibilities with Intel microcode updates that have caused this problem for others, but this did not resolve the issue for me.  Prior to what I assumed would be a normal Ubuntu update, this machine, which was installed with 18.04 LTS from scratch, worked well for months.  I am not a Linux power user, and not sure how to proceed to resolve this problem.  I would appreciate any suggestions in getting this taken care of while keeping the proprietary NVIDIA drivers, which are necessary for some of my Linux use cases.

Comment: Can you boot to an older kernel from the GRUB menu? Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot and access the login screen you could try reinstalling ubuntu desktop and reconfigure gdm3 or lightdm depending on which you are.
While on your login screen, get into a tty (CTRL+ALT+2 or CTRL+ALT+3)
Then on this terminal, login as root and do the following:

```
$ apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop  
$ dpkg-reconfigure gdm3  
#or  
$ dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Try logging in again on the original tty (CTRL+ALT+1)

Comment: I tried the commands above, but still no luck.  I can log in to the command line terminals (CTRL-ALT-F2), and can also use the full GUI if I use GRUB and resume, but the system hangs on the splash screen if I let the system start up without intervening and then type in my credetnails from the desktop.

Comment: Oh so you mean that if you don't touch anything when booting, the system hangs on the empty purple screen ? Maybe try installing the correct graphics driver, the command `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` (as root user) will retrieve the appropriate driver for your graphics card and install everything automagically.

Comment: Otherwise you can try the fex alternatives described here:  https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/